# hide the WinBar (TermDebug)

Tags: terminal, mouse

Vim 8.1 add a new :Termdebug command with a really good gdb integration.
If the `mouse` option is set, there is also a visual bar appearing on vim.
Here is an extract of the man:

```
If 'mouse' is set the plugin adds a window toolbar with these entries:
  Step          :Step 
  Next          :Over
  Finish        :Finish
  Cont          :Continue
  Stop          :Stop
  Eval          :Evaluate
This way you can use the mouse to perform the most common commands.  
You need to have the 'mouse' option set to enable mouse clicks.
                                                               :Winbar
You can add the window toolbar in other windows you open with: 
  :Winbar
```

My problem is, I would like to keep the mouse option on my configuration, but I would like to hide this bar, either at run-time with a command or preferably from the beginning in the *vimrc*.
Is it possible to do so and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about hiding it from the start, but what works to remove it after it was added is the following:

```
:aunmenu WinBar
```

I had one time where this did not work for some reason, but I cannot pinpoint the reason.

Note: It only works if you execute it in the window that has the toolbar

Note2: If you have other element in the window toolbar, those will get removed too. If you don't want this, you should explictly specify which elements to remove:

```
:aunmenu WinBar.Next
:aunmenu WinBar.Step
```

etc..

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like this was made to be configurable unfortunately. This is from the plugin itself:

```
if has('menu') && &mouse != ''
    call s:InstallWinbar()
```

I think your only options are to

1. Make your own command that will quickly turn `mouse` off and then back on again
2. Comment out these two lines located in: `.../Vim/vim##/pack/dist/opt/termdebug/plugin/termdebug.vim`